# My code is strangely not working

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int n,x,y,s=0,p=1 ;
    int nr=0,nr1=0 ;


    cout<<"n=" ;
    cin>> n ;
    cout<<"x=" ;
    cin>> x ;
    cout<<"y=" ;
    cin>> y ;

    while(n!=0)
        {


            if(n%10%x==0)

                {s=s+n%10 ;
                 n=n/10 ;
                 nr++ ;
                 }

            if(n%10<y)

                {p=p*(n%10) ;
                n=n/10 ;
                nr1++ ;
                }


        }

    cout<<"s="<<s<<"\n" ;
    cout<<"nr="<<nr<<"\n" ;
    cout<<"p="<<p<<"\n" ;
    cout<<"nr1="<<nr1<<"\n" ;
}
```

The Ideea of the program is to add the digits of a number n that divide with x and count them , and multiply the digits that are smaller then y and count them aswell .
If I give y a value  equal or high than 6, the program runs , the sum is ok but the product isn't.
Example :
I give n the value 123456
x the value 2 and y the value 6

```
n=123456
x=2
y=6
s=12
nr=3
p=15
nr1=3
```

The n's digits that divide with 2 are 2 , 4 and 6 so the sum is 12. Perfect!
But the product should be 1x2x3x4x5 , because the digits are  under 6 and nr1 the number of digits should be 5.

If I give y a value under 6 it just dosen't work...
For example we keep the same values for n and x and give y the value 4.

The whole output is :

```
n=123456
x=2
y=4
```

it dosen't even calculate s p nr and nr1...
WHY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Federic said you're removing a digit from n in both cases. Here, since you're using if statements and not if-else both these can run in the same iteration which would(or could) reduce your n by 2 digits every time.

Solution:

Remove n=n/10; from both cases and do it outside(and after) both if statements.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
    {
        int n,x,y,s=0,p=1 ;
        int nr=0,nr1=0 ;

        cout<<"n=" ;
        cin>> n ;
        cout<<"x=" ;
        cin>> x ;
        cout<<"y=" ;
        cin>> y ;

        while(n!=0)
            {
                if(n%10%x==0)
                    {
                        s=s+n%10 ;
                        nr++ ;
                    }

                if(n%10<y)
                    {
                        p=p*(n%10) ;
                        nr1++ ;
                    }
                n=n/10;
            }

        cout<<"s="<<s<<"\n" ;
        cout<<"nr="<<nr<<"\n" ;
        cout<<"p="<<p<<"\n" ;
        cout<<"nr1="<<nr1<<"\n" ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are removing digits from your number in both cases:

```
  if(n%10%x==0)
  {
       s=s+n%10 ;
       n=n/10 ; //*********
       nr++ ;
  }

  if(n%10<y)
  {
       p=p*(n%10) ;
       n=n/10 ; //*********
       nr1++ ;
  }
```

Look at the two lines commentend with:

```
//*********
```

Comment: I have removed n=n/10 from the product block and now after it compiles is outputs litteraly nothing @Federico

Comment: Maybe you have to move it after two `if`s (obviously removing it from the body of both the `if`).
So, the meaning will be: 
I check if this digit is in this or in this case, then, i remove this digit anyway.
exactly as @Devon showed to you.